# Deploying war throws class not found exception in docker

Tags: java, tomcat, docker

I am deploying a war file in tomcat, I get  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.i18n.util.LocaleMapper exception.

Tomcat Dockerfile has the classpath defined

```
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/jdk1.8.0_161
ENV CLASSPATH ${JAVA_HOME}/lib/orai18n-11.2.0.3.jar
```

In Docker instance the classpath is accepted:

```
root@aa649d0d1b5e:/usr/local/tomcat# export
.....
declare -x CLASSPATH="/usr/jdk1.8.0_161/lib/orai18n-11.2.0.3.jar"
.....
```

Below is the docker instance exception.

```
tomcat_1    | 06-Feb-2018 05:39:34.138 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:             
tomcat_1    |  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/abc]]             
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)                                                                                  
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)                                                                       
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)                                                                               
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)                                                                                 
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)                                                                                 
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)                                                                            
tomcat_1    |   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)                                                                               
tomcat_1    |   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)                                                                                              
tomcat_1    |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)                                                                       
tomcat_1    |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)                                                                       
tomcat_1    |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)                                                                                                                 
tomcat_1    | Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/i18n/util/LocaleMapper                                                                                   
tomcat_1    |   at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.setEncoding(XMLReader.java:985)                                                                                        
tomcat_1    |   at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.checkXMLDecl(XMLReader.java:3367)                                                                                      
tomcat_1    |   at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.pushXMLReader(XMLReader.java:575)                                                                                      
tomcat_1    |   at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.pushXMLReader(XMLReader.java:279)                                                                                      
tomcat_1    |   at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:240)                                                                                              
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1521)                                                                                    
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser.parseWebXml(WebXmlParser.java:119)                                                                 
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1114)                                                                          
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)                                                                      
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)                                                                      
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)                                                                      
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)                                                                     
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)                                                                                  
tomcat_1    |   ... 10 more                                                                                                                                              
tomcat_1    | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.i18n.util.LocaleMapper                                                                                 
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)                                                           
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)                                                           
tomcat_1    |   ... 23 more                                                                                                                                              
tomcat_1    |                                                                                                                                                            
tomcat_1    | 06-Feb-2018 05:39:34.153 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/usr/loca
/tomcat/webapps/abc.war]                                                                                                                                              
tomcat_1    |  java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina
.StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/abc]]                                                                                                                       
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)                                                                       
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)                                                                               
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)                                                                                 
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)                                                                                 
tomcat_1    |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)                                                                            
tomcat_1    |   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)                                                                               
tomcat_1    |   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)                                                                                              
tomcat_1    |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)                                                                       
tomcat_1    |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)                                                                       
tomcat_1    |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)                                                                                                                 
tomcat_1    |                                                                                                                                                            
tomcat_1    | 06-Feb-2018 05:39:34.157 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/to
cat/webapps/abc.war] has finished in [8,864] ms                                                                                                                       
tomcat_1    | 06-Feb-2018 05:39:34.160 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/loca
/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
```

Any help to resolve the issue will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include orai18n-mapping.jar in your library.

Check this blog:
http://tomacree.blogspot.pe/2010/09/running-oracle-mapviewer-in-apache.html

You can find orai18n-mapping.jar in JDev version 11.2 (you can download the Java Edition, it is a 112MB zip file, not need to install).

Jar location: ../modules/oracle.nlsrtl_11.1.0/orai18n-mapping.jar

JDev: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/jdev11124download-1970562.html

Here is orai18n-mapping.jar on my Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1g3C-rEh0iTM6wxtivKueeVAumm04gmV1